# How can I best display these options?

Tags: interaction-design, labeling

We have a converter that enables you to state what amount you want in a currency or the amount you have in a currency.

The problem I find is that we have these radio buttons that need to be selected to confirm which one you mean and then click on submit.

I find we are confusing most users plus with the added radio buttons we get users typing in both input fields. I was wondering how I could simplify it, or make it more clear on what they are doing.

Bearing in mind the requirement for business purposes states we have `I want` and `I have` both there. So I was hoping maybe someone would help me conjure up a new innovative user experience for this converter? Appreciate your help.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZxtWs.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Why is that requirement in there? On has to understand the requirement to be able to provide an alternative.

Comment: Well it's the two main reasons people trade, they either have a currency they need to convert to another or they currently want a currency. The words help answer people coming at the same thing from different angles. I'll get my BA to get me more information for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a. radio  buttons are absolutely redundant here
b. you can have 2 input fields editable if you want - 
   if you type in "I want" value - the "I have" value will be populated automatically. E.g.  if you  type in 10 EURO as I have, system automatically will calculate that you will get 12.9620 dollars aver conversion, and vice versa if you type 15 dollars as I want,  system will tel you how much you need to have in Euro.

alternatively you can disable editing of "I want" field.

See how google converter is donw

https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=10+eur+to+usd&oq=10+eur+to+usd&gs_l=serp.3..0i7l2j0j0i7.17876.17876.0.18297.1.1.0.0.0.0.101.101.0j1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.kGJZDsW0K_A&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=a1aa12b56862839c&bpcl=35277026&biw=1252&bih=609

Comment: Haha yeah I guess it could work. Google oh google. Thanks @Mike Sorokin

Answer (score 3):

@Anicho: I have seen a good example of this: http://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/

Also wouldn't in be better to have "I have" as 1st option, my understanding most of people wouldn't really know how much money they want, lets say to take on their holiday, but they would know how much money they are willing to spend.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense thanks for point out the "I have" option

Answer (score 2):

Another option is make `have` and `want` options in a dropdown menu, so you start with `I |have| |100| |USD|` and they can switch it to `I |want| |100| |USD|`. This way there's no confusion about what the radio button does, since the selection is obvious (want/have).

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues:

"I want". I want a billion dollars. But, realistically, I might be here only to get 100 dollars. I think the labels need to be a bit more explicit.

Can a user only do one or the other? If so, I wouldn't list two fields with radio buttons, but make one field, and then have one drop-down list, where you pick the type of transaction. (or, alternatively, keep the radios, but still only use one text field).

Comment: Users can only do one at a time. Of course have the option to come back and do the other if they so wish but that would make there trade just made reversed unless they doing it to different accounts.

Comment: Instead of I want and I have I am using I am buying and I am selling its a bit more straight to the point and clear.

Comment: If they can only do one of the two, then definitely use only one text field.

Answer (score 1):

Put the radio button before I want and I have.
Put the radio button,  I want, text box, and currency dropdown in a div. Same for the I have option.
Change the background colour of each div and add some padding so they are spaced. 
This should make it more obvious that there are two options and users won't input in to both fields.